# After update to Jelly Bean I am asked to select the E-Mail protocol. Which one should I choose?

Tags: email, 4.1-jelly-bean

Has anyone come across with sync-in email accounts using the native app?

For example:

I known a Bell.net account (Provided by Bell Canada), which uses Hotmail.com server. On Ice Cream Sandwhich I was able to punch in my email & password and it would automatically connect to my email no issues.

When I upgraded to 4.1.1 Jelly Bean it prompt me to select "POP", "IMAP" or "Exchange" setting. Is anyone else experiencing this with either a Bell.net or Hotmail.com accounts?

Answer (score 5):

Modern email clients are often able to detect the email server settings just from the username / password tuple.

If you are suddenly asked for an protocol (and possible outgoing/incoming mail server settings) then you should look them up on your mail providers homepage.

**E.g.,** a [quick Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=bell.net%20email%20settings) came up with [this page for Bell Canada](http://internet.bell.ca/index.cfm?method=content.view&content_id=1067).